# MDCChip selected image is displacing my title label

Tags: swift, material-design, md-chip

I'm implementing MDCChips in collection views in my application, but I'm encountering an issue that I can't solve.

When I add an selectedImageView to my chip and I select the chip in my collection view, the image is shown as intended, but the title is displaced due to the apparition of the image.

I've tried playing with the intrinsic content and the UIEdgeInsets, but I can't seem to find a workaround for this.

Is there some way to avoid this happening? I'd like the image to appear without displacing anything else in the chip view.

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "identifierChips", for: indexPath) as! MDCChipCollectionViewCell
    let chipView = cell.chipView
    chipView.selectedImageView.image = UIImage(named: "tickIcon")

    return cell
}
```

Any tip or help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to achieve it. It is kinda hacky, but as long as it works... And lacking another solution... Suits me!

I added this code to be executed every time the cell is selected.

```swift
chipView.imagePadding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: -padding)
```

And this code to be executed every time the cell is deselected.

```swift
chipView.imagePadding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

So esentially the padding value is the width of the image, when you select the cell the image will appear but you remove the right padding of the image with the total width of the image, so it doesn't affect the label.

When you deselect the view, the image will disappear so you restore the padding to zero.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to get, What is an issue in your code but I can suggest to you if anything will work then it's good.

1. If an image has a title then check your imageView's Content mode.
2. If you are using Lable for a title then debug your UI & check your constraints (if you use constraints)

Let me know if still, you are facing issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the image is merely a UIImageView, and the image view content mode would only affect the way that the image is displayed, right?. Also, I don't have constraints since I'm using a Material component with a preset view.

Comment: @Roberto Did check it with change content mode? Is a suggestion works for you?

Comment: @Roberto can you please add more code ?? With screenshots of your code result & expected code result?